# Verifying Darboux theorem Proof 2

Tags: calculus

I am trying to verify a statement mentioned under "Proof 2" of the Darboux theorem here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)#Proofs).
It states that as ${t\to a}$ ${g(t) \to f'(a)}  $ and similarly as ${t\to b}$ ${g(t) \to f'(b)} $. I am trying to prove ${t\to a}$ ${g(t) \to f'(a)}$  as below $$\lim_{t\to a} g(t) = f'(a)$$
Assuming that $a<= t <=c$ 
$$\lim_{t\to a} \frac{f(2t -a) - f(a)}{(2t-a)-a}$$ 
now if we substitute t=a we get $\frac{0}{0}$ so applying Lhopitals rule
$$\lim_{t\to a} \frac{2f'(2t -a) -f'(a)}{2}$$
now taking the limit we get
$$ = \frac{2f'(2a -a) -f'(a)}{2}$$ 
$$ = \frac{2f'(a) -f'(a)}{2}$$
$$ = \frac{f'(a)}{2}$$
which is not $f'(a)$ .
I think i am doing something wrong here, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of $f(a)$ with respect to $t$ is zero! So, after the application of L'Hopital's rule, you should consider the limit
$$\lim_{t\to a} \frac{2f'(2t -a)-0}{2}.$$

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I totally forgot about that. Now $g(t)$ approaches $f'(a)$